# Differentiability and Monotonic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, axiom-of-choice

I just read proof from Royden of theorem: 'Every Monotonic functions are differentiable almost everywhere.' But proof use Vitali Covering Lemma. But Vitali Covering Lemma is based on fact if we assume Axiom of choice to be true. Is theorem 'Every monotonic function differentiable a.e.' is also dependent on AC or is there some other proof of this fact not depending on Axiom of choice.

Note: We are taking axiom of countable choice to be true.(We are not even allowing axiom of dependent choice)

Comment: Without the axiom of choice measure theory breaks down completely, the Lebesgue measure need not be $\sigma$-additive, for example. So what does it mean "almost everywhere" in your question, when the axiom of choice is not assumed?

Comment: @AsafKaragila σ- additivity of Lebesgue measure is not dependent on Axiom of choice as much as I can see when I am restricted only to σ-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets

Comment: If the real numbers is a countable union of countable sets (and this can in fact happen), then there is no countably additive measure on $\Bbb R$ which vanishes on singletons.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay then I need to change my question a little bit. I am assuming axiom of countable choice to be true but not AC. Now can we prove this theorem. Sorry for mistake.(Without axiom of countable choice we can't do anything in Real analysis)

Comment: @AsafKaragila We can still define measure zero in a nontrivial way (meaning, no interval is measure zero) without any choice. That's all that's needed here. The definition is the standard one: $A$ is measure zero iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a covering of $A$ with countably many open intervals whose lengths add up to at most $\epsilon$. (With a bit of choice, we can remove the requirement that the covering be countable.)

Comment: @Sushil I presented this result in detail in lecture this term, I did not use Vitali's covering. It is true, though, that I used that countable unions of countable sets are countable.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Sir can you please send me your lecture notes. I can mail you?

Comment: @Andres: Thanks.

Comment: @Andres Sir I am not able to find your email id. Can you please help me how to prove this result

Comment: @AndresCaicedo although I forget to mentione in question the domain on which function is defined. Now I realized that theorem I proveed is when function defined on [a,b]. Does it also follows 'Every monotonic function on E are differentiable a.e.' even when outer measure of E is finite or infinite.